# is $wpdb->get_results() safe enough

Tags: database

##### original question

if I use the get_results() functions is this safe enough from mysql injection attacks?

```php
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results("select * from tableA where B = C");
```

Or should this have some kind of prepare first?
What's the best practice?
How should we do it in our present time December 2021 ?

##### update

so I should use this instead?

```php
global $wpdb;
$my_variable = "sometext";
$prep = $wpdb->prepare("select * from tableA where B = %s", $my_variable);
$wpdb->query($prep);
```

Comment: If you're using variables, no it's not safe. Have you read the documentation? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#protect-queries-against-sql-injection-attacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to always use $wpdb->prepare() before $wpdb->query() or $wpdb->get_results() if your queries depend on dynamic variables